# Github actions push docker image to gcp artifact registry access token has insufficient scopes

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, github-actions, google-artifact-registry

I'm trying to get a github actions flow going where it builds a microservice and deploys it.

I have the workflow:

`action.yml`

```
name: 'Build and Deploy Docker Microservices'
description: 'Build and Deploy Docker Microservices'
inputs:
  service:
    description: 'Which Service To Build'
    required: true
  docker_image:
    description: 'Docker image url'
    required: true
  repository_url:
    description: 'The URL of the repository'
    required: true
  project_id:
    description: 'The GCP Project ID'
    required: true
  workload_identity_provider:
    description: 'The GCP Credentials JSON'
    required: true
  service_account:
    description: 'The GCP Service Account'
    required: true
  artifact_url:
    description: 'The GCP Artifact URL'
    required: true

runs:
  using: "composite"
  steps:
    - name: 'GCP AUTH'
      id: auth
      uses: 'google-github-actions/auth@v1'
      with:
        token_format: 'access_token'
        project_id: ${{ inputs.project_id }}
        workload_identity_provider: ${{ inputs.workload_identity_provider }}
        service_account: ${{ inputs.service_account }}

    - name: Login to Artifact Registry
      uses: docker/login-action@v3
      with:
        registry: gcr.io
        username: oauth2accesstoken
        password: ${{ steps.auth.outputs.access_token }}

    - name: 'Build Docker Container'
      shell: bash
      run: |
        docker build -t ${{ inputs.docker_image }}:${{ github.sha }} -f ./${{ inputs.service }}/docker/cloud/Dockerfile .

    - name: 'Push Docker Container'
      shell: bash
      run: |
        docker push ${{ inputs.docker_image }}:${{ github.sha }}

    - id: 'deploy'
      uses: 'google-github-actions/deploy-cloudrun@v1'
      with:
        service: ${{ inputs.service }}
        image: ${{ inputs.docker_image }}:${{ github.sha }}
```

But it fails on the push docker image with

```
unauthorized: access token has insufficient scopes
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

The service account being used has the role `Artifact Registry Administrator`

I've also added permissions to create an access token and such, I've tried a handleful of custom permissions, but nothing seem to actually be the magical one to make this work.

Comment: Could solve your issue, but not sure, but it will increase the security (at least decrease the risk to have a service account key file). Have a look on workload identity federation with GithubAction https://github.com/google-github-actions/auth

Comment: same error, but will update the post with my new config

Comment: it's not enough to use the auth action, you have to configure a workload identity pool and give it access to your gcp resources https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/identity-security/enabling-keyless-authentication-from-github-actions

Comment: followed that twice now, and still the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was the docker image name was malformed, it was pointing to a completely different location, fixing it fixed my problems